# Calling C++ from C# passing a char**

Tags: c#, c++

I am calling a C++ dll that returns a list of strings as a char **.  I am getting confused with Marshalling the pointers and can't figure out how to get the strings into a string[].

C++ Call

```
int GetPropertyNames (Handle Group, char **propertyNames, size_t numberOfPropertyNames);
```

This is a library that was supplied to me so I have no way to modify the dll.

I have tried

```
[DllImport("some.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern int GetPropertyNames(IntPtr group, ref IntPtr[] propertyNames, uint numberOfProperties);

...

IntPtr[] ptr.

ptr = new IntPtr[numberOfPropertyNames];
GetPropertyNames(group, ref ptr, numberOfPropertyNames);
```

And ptr comes back as 1 element no matter how many I allocated it with.

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me.

Comment: Is that C ? not C++ perhaps?

Comment: Might be a dumb question, but I don't know C#. How does `ref IntPtr[]` map to `char**`? If anything I'd expect `int**` instead.

Comment: `char**` is a pointer to an array of `char*` pointers.  `ref IntPtr[]` is a reference to an array of pointers.

Comment: Microsoft provides an example of this kind of scenario, see [Marshaling Different Types of Arrays](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/marshaling-different-types-of-arrays), in particular the "TestArrayOfStrings" example. Though I suspect that example is more for input than output. Does ` GetPropertyNames()` allocate memory for the output strings? Or is the caller expected to allocate the memory? Do you have a C++ example showing `GetPropertyNames()` in action? In this situation, I would probably just end up handling the marshalling manually via the `Marshal` class.

Comment: You, probably, should try to use `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]ref String propertyNames`

Comment: You should tag this with `[pinvoke]` so that you can pull in the folks who know this stuff inside out. Sometimes http://pinvoke.net can help with this. It's focused on Win32 interop, but there are tons of examples there. See if you can find a copy of Adam Nathan's book (_.NET and COM: The Complete Interoperability Guide_); all answers are there